# TFS2017 not able to use shared Queries for other team members

Tags: tfs

We recently add a new team in  our project. Someone in the new team could not be able to use the shared queries feature in work items page.

However all members in my team works well. I have double confirmed  the permissions on Shared Queries, both teams are set correctly and totally the same.

The most interesting thing is  not all members in the new team couldn't use the Shared Queries. Which  really confused me, and checked every person in both teams, there are not any explicitly deny set for Shared Queries. What problem does we have?

Comment: Did you get any related error info for the users who couldn't use Shared Queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you should also check the **access levels** of those accounts in TFS server.

> Access levels enable administrators the ability to provide their user
> base access to the features they need and only pay for those features.
>
> *[**About access levels**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/access-levels)*

**Stakeholders** cannot save to "Shared Queries",if you need access to the following features, you need to be have Basic access or higher:

> 1. Stakeholders cannot view markdown README files defined for
>    repositories.
> 2. In order to add users and assign licenses for VSTS, stakeholders
>    must be added to the Project Collection Administrators group. Also,
>    they must use the current Users page (not the Streamlined User
>    Management page under preview) in order to manage users. To learn
>    more, see Manage users and access.
> 3. Stakeholders can only view and approve releases.
> 4. Stakeholders can assign existing tags to work items, but not create
>    new tags.
> 5. Stakeholders cannot change the backlog priority order (all items are
>    added at the end of the backlog), assign items to an iteration using
>    drag and drop, use the mapping pane or forecasting.
> 6. Stakeholders cannot move cards on the board to update status, set
>    the values of fields shown on cards, or set or view team capacity.
> 7. Stakeholders can save queries under My Queries but **cannot save under
>    Shared Queries.**

In other words, it's a  licensing issue, try to change the user access level from Stakeholders to Basic. About how to do this, please refer this tutorial in MSDN:[How to change access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/change-access-levels)